# seaching all excel files with os.walk (), then call the function to read this excel, How can I do it?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openxlsx

I created a function to read excel sheet read_Excel_file(path) that return a list contains some data from a specific Column.

and in the main code I search all the excel files (where the name start Design) and this excel file should be saved in a folder  `Design`. If I find the excel file, I call the function `read_Excel_file`.

Please find below the code:

```
import openpyxl as opx
import os


for r, d, f in os.walk('.'):
    for file in f:
        if '.xlsx'  and 'design' in file:
            #print(r)
            if r.endswith('\Design'): 
                print(file)                     
                read_Excel_file(file)
```

but I get the error :

> *No such file or directory*

even if I am sure that I have this file in my directory

Do you think that I have path problem?

PS: I add `print(file)` just to check the name of the file, but when `read_Excel_file(file)` after that I have the error.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Hey @Meryem, I think you can simplify your code to a **minimal** working example. As far as I understood your problem, it's only related to finding and opening files using `os.walk(...)` and the openxlsx part is not relevant at all...

Comment: @ Konstantin, I import openxlsx  to read some data from Excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File is just the name of the file. You are missing the complete adress.
You need to add the root part of the address.

Just do:

```
filepath = os.path.join(r, file)
read_Excel_file(filepath)
```